# python program not printing using JSON information

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking for help on figuring out how to properly print the country name and population of that country.  I am using the code below from the "Python Crash Course" book, and in the book it shows this program printing correctly, where as for me it simply says

"------------------
(program exited with code: 0)

Press any key to continue . . ."

Any clue why it wouldn't be printing correctly?

```
import json
filename = 'population_data.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    pop_data = json.load(f)

for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] == 2010:
        country_name = pop_dict['Country_Name']
        population = int(float(pop_dict['Value']))
        print(country_name + ": " + str(population))
```

Comment: Perhaps `pop_dict['Year']` is a string?

Comment: Could you post a reduced example of "population_data.json"

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some things. I hope this helps you.
Python scrtip

```
import json
filename = 'population_data.json'
with open(filename) as f:
pop_data = json.load(f)
newdic=pop_data.values()
for item in newdic: 
    if item['Year'] == 2010 :
        print("country name is %s population is %s "%   (item['Country_Name'],item['population']))
```

This is json file which i assumed

```
{
"One":{
    "Year":2010,
    "Country_Name":"India",
     "population":78.5
},
"Two":{
    "Year":2012,
    "Country_Name":"XYZ",
     "population":88.5
},
"Three":{
    "Year":2010,
    "Country_Name":"ABC",
     "population":108.5
}
```

}